# How to create a folder on Windows machine which can only be accessed by application?

Tags: windows, directory, permissions, working-directory, folder-permissions

I want to create a application specific folder from my application.

I want to create a folder, in which my application should be able to read, write and copy files and sub-directories. But at the same time I want this folder to be un-accessible (moved, copied or opened) from outside the application.

Any programming language should be fine. Please help.